# Default Validation Template not getting fired in WPF

Tags: validation, xaml, textbox, tooltip

My code goes as follows :

```
<TextBox >
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="SaveAsText" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" ValidatesOnExceptions="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <val:SaveTextValidator></val:SaveTextValidator>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip"
    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                    Path=(Validation.Errors), Converter={StaticResource errorConverter}}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Now when a validation error happens, **the ToolTip is getting displayed but the default validation template of making a TextBox border red is not firing** !!
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Tried your TextBox and the Validation.ErrorTemplate is showing up fine so something else must be the problem

Comment: @Meleak - If it is some other problem, how can I debug that ? I mean ToolTip is fine, but default not firing. Also no errors in output window!!

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the default style of the TextBox (basically saying: do nothing unless I tell you to).

I imagine there is some trigger in the default style that makes the border red. Either implement it your self or base your style on the current default.

```
<Style BasedOn={x:Type TextBox} ...>
```